# WooCommerce - Editor Sidebar Dissapears Once I Scroll up

Tags: html, css, wordpress, woocommerce

On the WooCommerce post editor, once you scroll down to see the rest of the content, the sidebar on the right also switches to the fixed position so that you don't have to scroll all the way back up to publish, save or make any other changes through the sidebar:

```
<div id="side-sortables" class="meta-box-sortables ui-sortable" style="position: fixed; top: auto; bottom: 20px;">
```

However as soon as you scroll up, the sidebar disappears. it seems like the position switches back to absolute:

```
<div id="side-sortables" class="meta-box-sortables ui-sortable" style="position: absolute; top: -933.25px;">
```

and when you scroll back down once again, it re-appears. at first I thought that's how it functioned until I found out it was some sort of a plugin/theme conflict:

> https://wordpress.org/support/topic/product-editor-sidebar-disappears-while-scrolling/

I installed the latest copy of Wordpress and Woocommerce with their default settings on a local server and it was the same. so it looks like it has nothing to do with any sort of plugin/theme conflict. I also tried this on three different browsers (Firefox, Chrome, Edge) and they all came up with same issue. I had a couple of errors in all of them but the one that caught my attention was the following warning on Firefox:

> This site appears to use a scroll-linked positioning effect. This may
> not work well with asynchronous panning; see
> https://firefox-source-docs.mozilla.org/performance/scroll-linked_effects.html
> for further details and to join the discussion on related tools and
> features! post.php

I also managed to get the sidebar fixed but then I couldn't scroll the sidebar itself:

```
#post-body.columns-2 #side-sortables {
  top: 97px !important;
  position: fixed !important;
}
```

So if there's a simple css solution to keep the sidebar static and scrollable, that's totally fine with me.

> Edit: It is also worth mentioning that once I collapse all four boxes
> on sidebar (Product image, Product gallery, Product categories,
> Product tags), I will never experience any scrolling issue but as soon
> as I expand any one of them, the sidebar will disappear once I scroll
> up. weird!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up fixing the issue with a better alternative.

From the Screen Options on the top right corner of your editor, uncheck **"Enable full-height editor and distraction free functionality"**. It'll limit the height of the description box to your desired size and you don't need to scroll through a long content.